# Data structures for efficiently finding small intersections of large collections

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The problem at hand is that I have a large number of large collections whose intersections are ordinarily quite small relatively. I'd like to find an auxiliary data structure that allows for efficient computation of those intersections. For the sake of argument everything fits in RAM somehow, everything is an integer, etc.... I.e., filling in the blanks for:

```py
class MySet:
    def __init__(self, collection: List[int]):
        pass

    def intersection(self, other: MySet) -> List[int]:  # or -> MySet if we also support iteration
        pass

a = MySet(range(0, 10**10, 2))  # might be slow
b = MySet(range(1, 10**10, 2))  # might be slow

res = a.intersect(b)  # ought to be nearly instantaneous since the intersection is empty
```

The problem I'm facing is that implementations I'm aware of have a runtime proportional to at least the size of the smallest set being intersected. E.g., for sets `A` and `B` runtimes of `O(min(|A|, |B|))` and `O(|A| + |B|)` (often with polylogarithmic factors) are what you might expect from hashsets, sorted trees, or other common solutions.

If `|A.intersect(B)| << min(|A|, |B|)` though it would be nice to have a solution with runtime proportional to the result size rather than the size of the intermediate data structures, especially if `min(|A|, |B|)` is still prohibitively large for a given application.

I'm not certain whether the problem is solvable or not, and I'm curious in results to the contrary as well. At least probabilisticly we have algorithms like the hyperloglog which efficiently support approximately counting the intersection, and if the data has certain properties like being sparsely interleaved then there are also good solutions, but I haven't been able to find a suitable general-purpose algorithm.

**tldr;**
Are there set-like data structures supporting intersection in `O(|A.intersect(B)|)` time rather than `O(min(|A|, |B|))` time?

Comment: Maybe this library? [Sorted Containers sortedset](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Maybe? At a glance it doesn't look like it though. It looks like it falls back to python sets for intersections http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/_modules/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html#SortedSet.intersection. I hadn't seen that library before though, and I think I might like it for other applications. Thank you.

Comment: It is indeed hard to tell without testing with your own data; the performance tests look like they were seriously conducted, and show good results for large, medium and small datasets for `intersection` and `intersection_update`: [performance tests](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) (scroll to 2/3rd of the page down) - there is a [talk at 2017 pycon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z2Ki44Vs4E)